# Powershell script to detect if a user installed Chrome?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

We can see that some computers have Google Chrome installed, but it's not installed under C:\Program Files. Some users have installed Chrome in their Local AppData folder and therefore we cannot manage this centrally (some computers are being used by multiple users).

Does anyone perhaps have a Powershell script to detect which users have installed Chrome in their Local AppData folder and/or on which computer?

I tried using this Powershell script, but unfortunately it doesn't find anything:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq 'Google Chrome'}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no certain way to find out if the user has installed chorme

```
# Check both the Program Files and AppData directories for Chrome installation
$paths = @(
    "$env:ProgramFiles\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
    "$env:ProgramFiles(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
    "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
)

$chromeInstalled = $false

# Iterate through the paths and check if the Chrome executable exists
foreach ($path in $paths) {
    if (Test-Path $path) {
        $chromeInstalled = $true
        break
    }
}
```

Or you could also check if it installed in the registry

```
# Function to check if Chrome is installed in the registry
function Check-ChromeInstallation {
    $paths = @(
        "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*",
        "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*",
        "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
    )

    foreach ($path in $paths) {
        $items = Get-ItemProperty $path
        foreach ($item in $items) {
            if ($item.DisplayName -like "*Google Chrome*") {
                return $true
            }
        }
    }

    return $false
}
```

Comment: Yes, you could use this command: 
Check-ChromeInstallation | Out-File -FilePath "output.txt"
or 
Check-ChromeInstallation > "output.txt"

Comment: Nowhere in the script, you have to save the function as a script, and from Powershell you call one of the commands in order to start the function. Just make sure in your Powershell that you are in the same directory